# Using CURL Windows to post json

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

```html
curl.exe -X POST "https://api.inxpress.com/imcs_gateway/c_1/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -D^
{^
   "request_id":"pm77",^
   "request_time":"2020-12-24",^
   "account":"accountname",^
   "password":"apikey",^
   "gateway":"UK",^
   "carrierCode":"C_1",^
   "origin":{^
      "city":"ROCHDALE",^
      "postal_code":"OL16 5DB",^
      "country":"GB"^
   },^
   "destination":{^
      "city":"Bellville",^
      "postal_code":"7530",^
      "country":"ZA"^
   },^
   "product_code":"P",^
   "content_type":"WPX",^
   "weight_unit":"kg",^
   "dimension_unit":"cm",^
   "currency":"GBP",^
   "insured_value":"3.00",^
   "dutiable":true,^
   "commercial_value":"5.00",^
   "pieces":[^
      {^
         "name":"Piece 1",^
         "weight":5.0,^
         "height":8.0,^
         "depth":12.0,^
         "width":12.0,^
         "quantity":1,^
         "custom_value":10.0^
      }^
   ]^
}
```

I'm trying to execute this batch file in windows but I must have a formatting problem with the data as the output is like this

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: request_id
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: request_time
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: account
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: password
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: gateway
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: carrierCode
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 8
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: city
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: postal_code
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: country
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 13
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: city
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: postal_code
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: country
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: product_code
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: content_type
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: weight_unit
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dimension_unit
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: currency
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: insured_value
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dutiable
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: commercial_value
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 9
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: weight
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: height
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: depth
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: width
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: quantity
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: custom_value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capital `-D` option is not in my `curl` at least, maybe you meant `-d` aka `--data`?

Anyway the problem seems to be that `curl` understands your request as multiple command-line parameters rather than a request string for `-D`.

At least you have to add `"` right after  `-D` and a space, and one at the end, and escape all `"` in the request as `^"`.

But even that may not be enough - then the easiest option is to read the request from a file with `curl --data @filename-of-request.txt`

If you want to keep everything in one file, try sending request data through a stream like this:

```
(
echo line 1 of your request 
echo line 2 of your request
...................
echo line N of your request
) | curl --data @-   OTHER-CURL-PARAMETERS-HERE
```

here:

- `echo something` outputs `something` to `stdout` stream (default - on screen)

  - `echo` simply outputs its commandline so it's much more tolerant to special characters in the command line, but you may still need to escape some of them with `^`
- `|` (pipe) redirects `echo`'s `stdout` into `curl`'s `stdin` stream
- `(` ... `)` make `cmd` bunch several `echo` output together

  - please note: the output will include line breaks
  - instead you can try bunching up all the text into one echo with `^`-at-line-end trick you used
- `--data @file` makes `curl` read POST data from file
- `@-` specifies `stdin` as file which is where `echo` output went

Comment: That appears to work. Thanks

Comment: Please specify which method did you use successfully in the end? If this answer satisfies you please mark it as accepted to signal that your question doesn't need more answers - although you might want to do it after a while if you would like to see if someone else comes up with a better answer. Thanks.

Comment: I put the data in a file